# Issue while translating attributed text in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a `UIButton`. The `UIButton` is added under tableview cell. Now I want to make it underline. So if I make text attributed programmatically then it will create a new Object of `MutableAttributedString` for every cell which will increase memory. If create attributed string from storyboard then it does translate in another language . So please tell me how can I make it happen?

Code

```
 let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: orignalString, attributes: attributes)
//some code
                self.labelProgress.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: how are you reusing your cells?, If you are reusing correctly your cells then the memory should not grow further than a point

Comment: I am reusing cell with identifier. However I will write the code for attributed string in cellForRowAtIndexPath as let attrString:MutableAttributedString = MutableAttributedString()

Comment: Are you adding the UILabel to the cell programatically?

Comment: According to what you are describing, memory should not be an issue. If are to use localized strings then you will have to set the text programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to make a string underlined is to use an attributed string. So if you have table cells with such strings, a new attributed string has to be created any time a table cell is changed. Even the storyboard has to create new attributed strings for each update. But I do not see how this could ever cause noticeable memory usage.

Anyway, if you want to localize attributed strings, you have to do this by yourself programmatically. In general, I prefer this method for all UI elements because it gives you more control. You can simplify the whole process by using the following extension:

```
extension String {

    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
    }

}
```

You can then define your translations as global constants like:

```
class Texts {

    class MyViewController {

        static let buttonTitle = "Edit".localized

    }

}
```

And set the text of your button with:

```
self.button.setAttributedTitle(
    NSMutableAttributedString(string: Texts.MyViewController.buttonTitle,
        attributes: [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue]),
        for: UIControlState()
    )
```

Comment: Why you do not see any memory issue here so let's say if I have 100 records in my tableview so the object for NSMutableAttributedString will be create 100 times

Comment: Please answer my question.

Comment: Table view cells are reused if they "leave" the visible window. So, depending on your table cell height there will be only 5 - 10 table cells visible at the same time. Also, ARC automatically deletes old attributed strings if they are replaced during cell update. Hence, the used memory size is constant. This will result in only 5 - 10 attributed strings existing at the same time.

Comment: I guess it is safe to assume that an attributed string will use only some more bytes of memory than a regular string does, being 2 or 4 bytes per character plus metadata. If we assume a string length of 20 characters, ALL attributed strings together will consume less than 1 kilobyte of RAM. With a current iPhone, having at least 1 gigabyte of RAM, I do not see how you could ever get into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the text style in the fonts menu in the attribute inspector or even if you want you can change the font itself. But your cells aren't supposed to augment your memory. there must be a glitch in your code. Would it be possible to post your code in the question?

Comment: It is. He wants to underline the word and I told him how.

Comment: NSMutableAttributedString(string: Texts.MyViewController.buttonTitle,
        attributes: [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue]),
        for: UIControlState(
    ) ) Due to think by writing this in cellForRowAtIndexpath we will have this problem